# ¿Cómo renombrar variables de un data.frame?

Tags: r, rstudio, dataframe

Necesito renombrar varias variables de un `dataset`. Tengo por ejemplo como variables a modificar:

```
Año 2018
Año 2019 
Año 2020
```

Necesitó cubrir los espacios en blanco por un guion bajo, es decir:
`Año_2018`, `Año_2019` y `Año_2020` pero sin tener que hacerlo una por una sino utilizando alguna función en R

Answer (score 0):

Teniendo un `data.frame` como el que mencionas:

```
df <- data.frame('id'=1:10, 
                 'Año 2018'=runif(10), 
                 'Año 2019'=runif(10), 
                 'Año 2020'=runif(10),  check.names = FALSE)
```

Puedes usar en primer lugar `colnames()` para obtener los nombres de columna y `gsub()` pra a modificar cualquier espacio (`\\s`) que tuvieras en cualquier variable

```
colnames(df) <- gsub('\\s', '_', colnames(df))
df

   id   Año_2018  Año_2019  Año_2020
1   1 0.45389549 0.5980924 0.4525708
2   2 0.51116978 0.5609007 0.1751268
3   3 0.20754511 0.5260277 0.7466983
4   4 0.22865814 0.9850952 0.1049876
5   5 0.59571200 0.5076418 0.8645449
6   6 0.57487220 0.6827881 0.6146450
7   7 0.07706438 0.6015412 0.5571595
8   8 0.03554058 0.2388687 0.3287773
9   9 0.64279549 0.2581659 0.4531314
10 10 0.92861520 0.7293096 0.5004410
```

También, recuerda que por defecto `data.frame()`normaliza los nombres de variable, pero usando un `.` en vez de un guión, si te sirve es incluso más sencillo hacer:

```
df <- data.frame(df)
```

Comment: @pmoracho gracias por la solucion