# ¿Cómo seleccionar variables a partir de una condición?

Tags: r, dataframe, dataset, studio

Tengo un dataset con varias variables, entre ellas:

```
ID     Articulo 2018 ARticulo 2019   Articulo 2020
12-A        12             15              NA
12-B        14              NA             19
30-D        NA             21               32
55-P        32              15              NA
```

Necesito seleccionar aquellos ID que vendieron artículos en 2018 o 2019, ya que existen campos sin ventas.

Answer (score 1):

Con R base:

```
df[!is.na(df$`Articulo 2018`) | !is.na(df$`ARticulo 2019`),]
```

Con `dplyr`

```
library("dplyr")

df %>% 
  filter(!is.na(`Articulo 2018`) | !is.na(`ARticulo 2019`))
```

Comentarios:

- Ten en cuenta que en tu ejemplo `ARticulo 2019` a diferencia del resto de las columnas tiene la `R` mayuscula
- Te conviene normalizar los nombres de las columnas, para evitarte el trabajo de agregar "backticks", revisa [esto](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/324767/31764) para hacerlo

Comment: **Selecciona las gasolineras que vendan gasolina 95 o 98** Es el enunciado real del problema. Entiendo que pide por aquellas gasolineras (ID_gasolinera) de las cuales no tienen NA en sus campos, ¿es correcto? @pmoracho

Comment: @Adrian, Normalmente el valor `NA` indica la ausencia de un valor, por lo que es correcto lo que dices. Pero no está de más que verifiques que valores posibles puedes tener, ya que en algunos casos el 0 o el NULL podrían indicar lo mismo.